# How to explain trend in limits of power sums?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, riemann-sum

first question here, so let's hope this goes well. In first-year university Calculus 1, I was learning about the formulas for sums of various powers. For example,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{k}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
$$\vdots$$
When used in the context of defining integration as the limit of Riemann sums, these often get used in the form
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n{k^a},a\in\mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}$$

Taking the limit of the first few formulas yields the following:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{k^0}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}n=\frac{1}{1}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n{k^1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^n{k^3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^5}\sum_{k=1}^n{k^4}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^5}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n{k^a}=\frac{1}{a+1}$$

Does the general trend in the last equation there hold for all $a$?

Comment: @Sil Thanks, obviously my Google skills are lacking...